# Wordpress .entry-content class will not properly align with sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

I've encountered another silly problem while trying to enable sidebar on pages on Wordpress Twentyeleven theme.

I've given my `.entry-content` class:

```
.entry-content {float:left !important;width:648px !important;}
```

excuse me for those `!important`s, I just don't dare to edit the default `style.css`...

Now I've added

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

By the end of `page.php`, just above the `get_footer` stuff... and sidebar apparently displays UNDER my `.entry-content`, on the right hand side....

I've trying giving the sidebar a `float:right`, but it still won't float.

[Here is an example.](http://nailian.ca/a027/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `<div id="main">` you have a `<div id="primary">`.
Set a width on the primary div and this is solved.

Like this: `#primary {width:400px;}`

Comment: One more question, giving #primary a width:400px solves the problem on pages. But the front page widget became extremely narrow...how do I solve that =p?

Comment: nvm the above question, i solved it by removing the <div style="float:right;"></div> wrapped around the get_sidebar php code!